# Php move upload file with ftp_put

Tags: php

```
move_uploaded_file();

ftp_put();
```

I have a input type file, let user upload image.

I try to save user's image to different server or sub domain.

So if anyone uploads a malicious file to the server it wont execute on my main server.

my questions are

1. how can I use **`move_uploaded_file`** with `ftp_put`?
2. should I get another server or sub domain is enough?

Comment: That's not necessary. Just move all uploaded files to a directory that is outside your web root and then make sure that you never execute those files (or pass them to an interpreter).

Comment: execute is not what i can control, user can follow the links and use browser to execute it

Comment: Not if the uploaded files are outside your web root.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using a different subdomain does not isolate it from your server: to do that you need to actually put it on a different machine. However, just saving the file to your server does not put you in any danger. The problem comes when something tries to interact with that file in an unsafe way. So for instance, a particular image viewing program may have a flaw in it which a malicious image could take advantage of. In this case, opening the uploaded image with this program would put you at risk.

Checking the file extension is not a legitimate way to determine the file type. For instance, I could write a malicious executable file and name it `my_vacation_pic.jpeg`. But once again, this will not be a problem for you to just save it on your filesystem.

If you want to figure out the file type, you want something like the unix `file` command, though I'm honestly not sure of what kind of risks are involved in opening possibly malicious files with this command.

However, `file` does not guarantee that there is nothing malicious in the file. For instance, it may tell you that it's an executable program of a certain variety, but it can't tell you that it's safe to run. Or it can tell you that it's a JPEG file, but it can't tell you that someone hasn't figured out a way to make it malicious if opened in a particular program. The best way to be sure that the file has nothing malicious in it is to use genuine anti-virus software (and course, there are no guarantees there either).

But really, the need for security depends entirely on what you intend to do with it. Just storing data does not mean it will be executed in anyway (unless there is a specific vulnerability with your OS, your file-system driver, or the program that is putting the file there).

### To your direct question:

The file upload just puts the uploaded content on your filesystem: you can then use any normal means you have of moving a file from one system to another. So for instance, ***yes***, you can use `ftp_put` to transfer the file from the local filesystem to a remote FTP server, just like you would with any other file. The variable `$_FILES["upload_key"]["tmp_name"]` tells you the filesystem path where the uploaded file was stored, so you should be able to pass that directly to `ftp_put` like you would any other file.

Answer (score 1):

`move_uploaded_file` and `ftp_put` are for different purposes.

`ftp_put` requires an FTP resource connection.

One way to do it is instead of use move_uploaded_file to place the temporary file, you send it right to the ftp server.

See this snippet:

```
<?php

// ... some code here ...

$remote_filename = 'path/to/your/uploaded/files/' . $_FILES['imagefile']['name'];
ftp_put($ftp_stream, $remote_filename, $_FILES["imagefile"]["tmp_name"]);
```

Answer (score 0):

As a general rule when you allow people to upload files, you test to see if its the file type you want an image file, JPEG, PNG etc, which as far as I know do not contain malicious software, unless its some horrible picture.

Something like

```
if($_FILES["imagefile"]["size"] >= 2120000) {
 echo "F2";
  die();
} else {
$imageData = @getimagesize($_FILES["imagefile"]["tmp_name"]);

if($imageData === FALSE || !($imageData[2] == IMAGETYPE_GIF || $imageData[2] ==            IMAGETYPE_JPEG || $imageData[2] == IMAGETYPE_PNG)) {
  echo "F2";
  die();
}
}
```

This is not the full code, but is an example of testing the image type and size.
I am not sure with ftp_put, but file_upload first puts it in a tmp folder on the server, then copies it to your desiginated location.

Comment: I have do all the check, just try not to save file in my main server, so if I missing anything, at lease the code won't execute on main server